# Does the Prandtl-Glauert correction use the airplane's Mach number, or its effective Mach number corrected for sweep?

Tags: aerodynamics

The Prandtl-Glauert correction adjusts the lift curve slope of an airfoil to different Mach numbers. Should the Mach number of the airplane be used or the effective Mach number that the leading edge of the wing sees, namely $M\cos(\Lambda_{LE})$.

Answer (score 0):

As far as we are considering the airfoil, it depends which profile do you take. In other words you have to take always the Mach considered in line with the chord of the airfoil.